# Scala implicit conversion misleading

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

I am little confused with the below code blocks of scala'a implicit conversion.

```
object Run {
   implicit class IntTimes(x: Int) {
      def times [A](f: =>A): Unit = {  //Definition
         def loop(current: Int): Unit =

         if(current > 0){
            f
            loop(current - 1)
         }
         loop(x)
      }
   }
}

object Demo {
   def main(args: Array[String]) {
      4 times println("hello")     //Call
   }
}
```

If we look at the "times" method definition, it takes a functional argument -> which does not take any input and returns A as output. But in the invocation of "times", the function println is passed which takes a string ("hello") as i/p and returns nothing (Unit).

This is just opposite to the definition. But this is working as expected. How is this working?

Comment: `println("hello")` is not a **function**. Is an expression which can conform to the type `=> Unit` thus it is a valid value for the `times` **method**. Also, `=> A` does not mean that it takes a function, it takes a [**by name parameter**](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/by-name-parameters.html).

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually from one of the Scala books, I get my understanding. I have given more details about it in the below comment.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/59GYnry4RgCGRQjBTQBliQ/7) you can check that it works as I explained.

Answer (score 3):

```
def times [A](f: =>A): Unit = {  //Definition
```

In this declaration, `f` is not a function parameter, it is a **by-name** parameter. This means that the expression that is passed in to `f` is evaluated each time the value of `f` is needed.

In the example the expression is `println("hello")` so this is evaluated 4 times.

Comment: Thanks for your response!

Actually I am following Programming in Scala book - 2nd edition (By Martin Odersky).
In chapter 9 (Control Abstraction), at pages -218 & 219, it is given that:  
"def myAssert(predicate: () => Boolean)" can be replaced by: "def byNameAssert(predicate: => Boolean)"

I have given the method signature alone for quick reference.

Comment: If we go by this book, "def times [A](f: =>A)" can be explanded to "def times [A](f: () => A)"

So ideally passing println("hello") to times method should throw type mismatch error because of String argument as input (where is nothing should be passed).

Am I missing some crucial points here ?

Please let me know if you need additional information.

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like "can be replaced" means "can be implemented in a different way" rather "is equivalent to". Whatever the book says, the two are not equivalent and if you change the signature of `times` to `(f: () => A)` it will not compile.

Comment: That is exactly right! Thanks Tim for your explanation. To sum up: "def myAssert(predicate: () => Boolean)"    is NOT equal to  "def byNameAssert(predicate: => Boolean)".

Comment: You can accept this to show that it has answered your question.

Comment: @user3103957 & Tim, It won't compile that is right, but not because `println` is taking a **String** as its argument, but because you would need to call it like this: `4 times { () => println("Hello") }` as you can see here, we are being explicit about creating a function of zero-arguments which will execute our expression _(making that expression effectively **lazy**)_, but because that is too boilerplate, Scala introduced **by name parameters** which are just sugar syntax over exactly this to reduce boiler plate.

Comment: @user3103957 Now as I told you in my first comment, the main problem with your confusion, is that you are believing that `println("Hello")` is a **function**, but it is not, there are not arguments and not body, is just an statement, a value of type **Unit** _(the return type of `println`)_.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez thank you for looking into this. Yes, when I try to call: "4 times { () => println("Hello") }" , it is throwing error which is correct.  I change the function definition to: def times [A](f:() =>A). Even then it is throwing error when I call "4 times { () => println("Hello") }" . But my expectation is that it would work.

Comment: I am getting this error:    error: value times is not a member of Int